# The SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type objects, not MySqlParameter objects

Tags: mysql, .net, insert, mysql-parameter

I have created a method that will insert any exceptions thrown into a table on "ExceptionLog" on MySql server.

ExceptionLog Table format

idExceptionLog int (AI)
User (varchar 45)
ErrorMessage (varchart 4000)

The problem is i keep getting the following error. Does anyone know why?

> The SqlParameterCollection only
> accepts non-null SqlParameter type
> objects, not MySqlParameter objects.

```
private void showErrorBox(String errorMsg, MessageBoxButtons btnokshow)
    {

        MessageBox.Show(errorMsg, "FS Manager Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

        // write to DB

        string username = System.Environment.UserName.ToString();
        string timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString();

          // Locals
        SqlConnection NasDB = null;
        SqlCommand inputError = null;
        int rows = 0;
        string spName = "ExceptionInsert";

        try
        {
            //Instantiate the DB connection setting the conn string
            using (NasDB = new SqlConnection(getConnectionString(ConnectionType.NAS)))
            {
                // Instantiate the command object that will fire the SP.
                using (inputError = new SqlCommand(spName, NasDB))
                {
                    // Finish setting up the command object
                    inputError.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    // Set up the SP params.


                    inputError.Parameters.Add(new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("ExceptionDate", MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.DateTime, (1)));
                    inputError.Parameters[0].Value = timestamp;

                    inputError.Parameters.Add(new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("User", MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.VarChar, (45)));
                    inputError.Parameters[1].Value = System.Environment.UserName.ToString();

                    inputError.Parameters.Add(new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("ExceptionMessage", MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.VarChar, (4000)));
                    inputError.Parameters[2].Value = errorMsg;

                   
                    // Now that the SP is completely set up and ready to go open the conn and fire the SP.
                    inputError.Connection.Open();
                    rows = inputError.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    // Close ASAP
                    inputError.Connection.Close();
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //showErrorBox(ex.ToString());
            throw ex;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some slight changes and am now getting the following error.

**

> Input string was not in a correct

**

This is the Stored proceedure i using and the method.

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

-- Routine DDL

---

DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`Admin`@`%` PROCEDURE `test`(
        IN  p_idExceptionLog                INT(32)       , 
        IN  p_ExceptionDate                 DATETIME      , 
        IN  p_User                          VARCHAR(45)   , 
        IN  p_ExceptionMessage              VARCHAR(4000)

```
 )
```

BEGIN

```
INSERT INTO ExceptionLog
     (
       id                    , 
       Date                  , 
       User                  , 
       Message                                      
     )
VALUES 
     ( 
       p_idExceptionLog                    , 
       p_ExceptionDate                     , 
       p_User                              , 
       p_ExceptionMessage                    
     ) ;
```

END

```
  private void showErrorBox(String errorMsg, MessageBoxButtons btnokshow)
    {

        MessageBox.Show(errorMsg, "FS Manager Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

        // write to DB

        string username = System.Environment.UserName.ToString();
        string timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString();

          // Locals
        MySqlConnection NasDB = null;
    //    MySqlCommand inputError1 = new MySqlCommand();
        MySqlCommand inputError = null;
               int rows = 0;
        string spName = "test";

        try
        {
            //Instantiate the DB connection setting the conn string
            using (NasDB = new MySqlConnection(getConnectionString(ConnectionType.NAS)))
            {
                // Instantiate the command object that will fire the SP.
                using (inputError = new MySqlCommand(spName, NasDB))
                {
                    // Finish setting up the command object
                    inputError.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    // Set up the SP params.

                    inputError.Parameters.Add(new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("p_idExceptionLog", MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.Int32, (1)));
                    inputError.Parameters[0].Value = "";

                    inputError.Parameters.Add(new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("p_ExceptionDate", MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.DateTime, (1)));
                    inputError.Parameters[1].Value = timestamp;

                    inputError.Parameters.Add(new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("p_User", MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.VarChar, (45)));
                    inputError.Parameters[2].Value = System.Environment.UserName.ToString();

                    inputError.Parameters.Add(new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("p_ExceptionMessage", MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.VarChar, (4000)));
                    inputError.Parameters[3].Value = errorMsg;

                    // Now that the SP is completely set up and ready to go open the conn and fire the SP.
                    inputError.Connection.Open();
                    rows = inputError.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    // Close ASAP
                    inputError.Connection.Close();
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //showErrorBox(ex.ToString());
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

All the classes inside `System.Data.SqlClient` are used for SQL Server database & not mysql.

In your code, replace `SqlCommand` with `MySqlCommand` and `SqlConnection` with `MySqlConnection`.

EDIT: See [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-ref-mysqlclient.html) page for the classes, you could use in this case.

Comment: Thanks, i had a felling it would be something simple like this as i am not used to working with MySQL.